# Cannot connect to current version of enterprise database (PostgreSQL) through PHP

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, php, versioning

Very new to PHP, and working on a simple edit page. I'm connecting to multiversioned Postgresql database that I set up in ArcMap using a PHP/HTML file. I'm using the `pg_connect` command with host/dbname/user/password as the input.

```
$MyPG = pg_pconnect('host=sv01213 dbname=surveys user=sde password=test', PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW);
```

It seems like when I make edits to the attributes through the PHP interface, I'm not seeing any changes have saved when I view the attributes in ArcMap. And also visa versa, when I make changes to the database through ArcMap, I'm not seeing the changes in a PHP query table. Even when I changed between the two versions of my postgresql database, I'm not seeing the PHP changes.

Does anyone have this same behavior? It almost seems like the PHP connection is making a separate static connection to the database or connecting to a alternative version. Is there a way to specify which version of the database that it finds?

Comment: I'm assuming that by "multiversioned database" you mean an ESRI  geodatabase. Only ESRI clients are versioning aware. If you are connecting using any other client either unversion you data or edit the versioned view that the geodatabse should automatically create.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about an ESRI geodatabase that was created using the "Create Enterprise Geodatabase" tool.

Comment: Never, **ever** use the `sde` login for data manipulation. There is no PHP geodatabase aware client -- It seems like a separate static connection because it is one.